# how can mock variables and functions in a testcase?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, testcase, react-18

**ParentComponent.js**

`

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import store from '../store_path'
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
import useTokenHook from 'hook_path'

const ChildComponent = loadable(() => import('../childComponent_path'))

export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const token = useTokenHook()
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false)
    const lang = store(state => state.lang)
    const apiCall = store(state => state.apicall)

    const myFn = async() => {
        const res = await apiCall();
        setData(res)
        setShowChild(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => { myFn() }, [])

    return(
        <>
            {showChild ? <ChildComponent data={data} /> : 'No data found'}
        </>
    )
}
```

`

I want to write JEST test cases for this component.
I am not able to mock store and values from store i.e. 'lang', 'apiCall'
I want to set some default value to 'lang' and i want to 'apiCall' to return specific value.
Also how can I set value 'setShowChild' to 'true' as initial value in testcase file

I tried few approaches to mock store like:

`

```
jest.mock('../store_path', () => ({
    lang: 'en',
    apiCall: jest.fn(() => {return someValue })
}))
```

`

Here I am getting error as:
TypeError: (0, _store.default) is not a function

I also tried

`

```
const appStore = jest.mock('../store_path', () => jest.fn())
appStore.mockImplementation(() => ({
    lang: 'en',
    apiCall: jest.fn(() => {return someValue })
```

}))
`

And Here I am getting error as:
appStore.mockImplementation is not a function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to mock default export in which case it can be mocked something like below

```
jest.mock('../store_path', () => ({
    default: jest.fn()
              // value for first store() call
              .mockReturnValueOnce('en') 
              // value for second store() call since it's async function
              .mockReturnValueOnce(() => new Promise((resolve) => { resolve('apiReturnVal')}))
}))
```